# How add drive to array using LSI Megaraid Storage Manager

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

I have an LSI 1068E raid card, with 4 disks, configured as 2 RAID1 pairs.  I'm not sure how, but I've ended up with a pair in a degraded state, and one of the disks from that pair shows as unconfigured (spare).

I've been through every option on the screen but can't figure out how to add this physical drive to virtual drive 0.

Can any offer step-by-step how to do this?  (Don't post general answers, since I've already done the 'general' stuff).  Do I have to do it from the BIOS?  (That would seem silly given the intent of the Storage Manager tool, but maybe they're punishing me for buying the entry level 1068E product and only let me make changes via the bios?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the capacity (0 Bytes). It seems that the controller can't talk properly to the disk (no serial number, no vendor or product. Maybe the disk is defective.

Try to reconnect the disk and/or reboot the server. Try to connect the disk alone to another computer to see whether the problem is the disk, the cable or the controller.

Comment: drive is ok - works fine on other sata system.  if I wipe out the raid then controller sees disk fine

Comment: My problem is that I can't the Java UI to work, so I can only use the command line. My next step would be to use `storcli /c0 /fall show` to see whether the controller thinks the disk still has RAID headers on it. `storcli /c0 /fall import` would fix that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wipe out the raid"? Have you tried to buy another disk and see if that works?